# Inheriting List<T>, want items to be retrieved by string ID value instead of index

Tags: c#

I have a class called Question. I have another class called Questions which is simply an inheritance of List creating a collection.

How can I make it so I can retrieve a Question object by it's ID property instead of the integer based index like this?:

```
Question q = Questions["someidhere"];
```

Basically I'm looking for the same functionality as a SqlDataReader object where you can retrieve a field based on the field name OR the index.

Comment: In addition to the answers suggesting using a dictionary, I would suggest using composition and not inheritance, where your class *has a* dictionary, and you might add an indexer to your class if you wish to support that functionality (which then delegates to the dictionary).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use a `List<T>` at all; use a [`Dictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Question>();
dict.Add("someidhere", new Question(...));
// ...
var q = dict["someidhere"];
```

Comment: I would note that this solution doesn't meet the stated requirement of retrieving "based on the field name OR the index."  Apparently the index part of that requirement wasn't very important, since @stringpoet has accepted the answer :-)

Comment: @phoog: Yeah, I thought about that, but from the way he described the problem I decided it was not actually a "real" requirement so much as a perceived one.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). 
This will do what you need it to do.

Comment: Oh, duh. I should have just slept better last night. That might have helped my brain. Thanks, lol!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) for this purpose. OrderedDictionary represents a collection of key/value pairs that are accessible by the key or index.